# Method for searching prime numbers loops forever

Tags: php, primes

I'm completely stuck here. This simple code below just stopped working. I adjusted some variables and now it loops for like a minute and then displays nothing.
The problem should be in the methods `isPrime` or `collectPrimes`. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
<?php

class PrimeNumbers
{
    const COLUMNS = 5;
    const MAX_PRIMES = 100;
    public $primes = array();

    public function isPrime($z) {
        for ($i = 2; $i < $z; $i++)
        {
            if (($z % $i) == 0) {
                return false;
            }   
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function collectPrimes() {
        $currentNumber = 1;
        while (count($this->primes) <= $this::MAX_PRIMES) {
            if ($this->isPrime($currentNumber)) {
                array_push($this->primes, $currentNumber);
                $currentNumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    public function outputGrid() {
        $columnCounter = 0;
        $output = "";

        $output .= "<table>";

        foreach ($this->primes as $prime) {
            if ($columnCounter == 0) {
               $output .= "<tr>";
            } else if ($columnCounter == $this::COLUMNS) {
                $output .= "</tr>";
                $columnCounter = 0;
            }
            $columnCounter++;
            $output .= "<td>".$prime."</td>";
        }

        $output .= "</table>";
        return $output;
    }
}

?>
<html>
<head><title>1000 Primzahlen</title></head>
<body>


<?php 

  $pr = new PrimeNumbers();
  $pr->collectPrimes();
  echo $pr->outputGrid();
  var_dump($pr->primes);

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried increasing the `max_execution_time` to see if it is just taking to longer?

Comment: Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: And, by the way, your algorithm is extremely inefficient.

Comment: You are using a very inefficient way to calculate the primes - chances are, it just takes a lot of time. Read up on the sieve of Erastothenes

Comment: I think that `$currentNumber++` is in the wrong place (the first non-prime you find will get the loop stuck)...

Comment: If you want to execute your code for ever yo can use: 'set_time_limit(0)'.

Comment: Thank you all, Iserni and atomman were right. I sure will check out that "sieve of Erastothenes".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `$currentNumber++` outside the if clause.

Whenever your code reaches a non-prime, it halts at that number, and doesnt continue to increment `$currentNumber`

Comment: But as said in the original comments, your code is extremely inefficient. Have a look at sieve of Erastothene [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that would help, but class constants in PHP shall be accesses with the keyword `self`

```
$this::COLUMNS    ====> self::COLUMNS
$this::MAX_PRIMES ====> self::MAX_PRIMES
```